# How to fix Cannot convert value of type ... to expected argument type inout _

Tags: swift3

I have this simple Swift3 code where if complains about `[Channel]`:

```
        var channels = [Channel]()
        ....

        for (_, json) in json["entities"] {
            let channel = Channel(json: json)
            self.channels += [channel]
                 ^ Cannot convert value of type [Channel] to expected argument type inout _
        }
```

This is the channel class:

```
class Channel {

    var uuid: String
    var title: String?
    var isPublic: Bool

    init(uuid: String) {
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.title = ""
        self.isPublic = false
    }

    init?(json: JSON) {
        self.uuid = json["uuid"].stringValue
        self.title = json["title"].stringValue
        self.isPublic = json["public"].boolValue
    }
}
```

Some postings indicate the message may be related to closures but I can't see a closure here.

How to fix this error in a simple for loop?

Comment: Well, what's the error? ...

Comment: Update your question with the complete and exact error message and point out the line causing the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is coming from the `+=` statement.  `Channel(json:)` is a failable initializer (note the `init?`) and it returns an Optional which must be unwrapped. So you are trying to apply `+=` to `[Channel]` and `[Channel?]` and the types are not compatible.  The error message is less than clear, because of the way `+=` is defined.

> ```
> public func +=<C : Collection>(lhs: inout [C.Iterator.Element], rhs: C)
> ```

Swift is unable to reconcile the type of `rhs` which is `[Channel?]` with the type of `lhs` which is `[Channel]`.

The fix is to unwrap the `Channel?` returned by the failable initializer `Channel(json:)`:

```
var channels = [Channel]()
....

for (_, json) in json["entities"] {
    if let channel = Channel(json: json) {
        self.channels += [channel]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@andig.  [1] your example cannot be compiled because both json and JSON are not defined. [2] Now let's assume you made a failable initializer init?(json: JSON){} correctly within Class Channel then vacawama's explanation is correct.  Changing your code to the below should work.

```
for (_, json) in json["entities"] {
    if let channel = Channel(json: json) {
        self.channels += [channel!]
    }
}
```